# What are debug options for docker on Mac doing? How do I see more verbose logging of docker client?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

From the look of the doc, I was under the impression that

```
docker -D -l debug --debug pull ...
```

will print verbose logging of some kind. But that wasn't the case.
Neither was the setting in advance setting:
[image]

Am I missing something? docker info does confirm I am in debug mode, though it doesn't say anything about logging location. Not sure if I am missing something here.

I'm on Mac

```
➜  ~ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:21:31 2018
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       e68fc7a
  Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:29:02 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found that there's rarely any debug logging in the source code, for this pull target especially there is none: https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/client/image_create.go